# JavaScriptDateTimeConverter gives different result on server

Tags: json, datetime

The code below works fine on local machine. On the other side, on server, it shifts date 1 day left.

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
```

The value returning from database is: 2010-09-16 00:00:00.000

JsonSerializer gives 2010-09-16 on local and gives 2010-09-15 on server..

any ideas?

---

To clarify the problem i made a simple test;

```
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Convert.ToDateTime("2010-09-16 00:00:00.000"), new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
Response.Write(str);
```

this code produce different results on different machines.. Why?

new Date(1284584400000) and new Date(1284588000000) or

Wed Sep 15 2010 23:00:00 and Thu Sep 16 2010 00:00:00

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with Java Date & Time API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a timezone issue.  Is your server in a different time zone?  Is it timezone-adjusting the dates and times?

Comment: I checked timezones. they are same on both of them.

Answer (score 0):

It's a timezone issue. By default JavaScriptDateTimeConverter uses UTC dates. You need to create a SerializerSettings object, and set

```
settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
```